# How to input a list of dictionaries from the user in python?

Tags: python

I've tried below code but it overwrites and makes duplicate of the last dictionary inputted.

```
name_lists=[]
d = {}
flag = ""
while(flag != "N"):
    d["name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
    d["surname"] = input("Enter a surname: ")
    d["patronmic"] = input("Enter a patronmic: ")
    d["id_number"] = input("Enter a worker's id number: ")
    name_lists.append(d)
    flag = input("Continue inputting data Y/N: ")
print(name_lists)
```

Comment: After appending d to name_lists, reset it to empty dict.

Comment: *there is only one dictionary here*. That is the problem. You keep appending the *exact same dict multiple times* to the list, `name_lists.append(d)`

Comment: @deceze (offtopic) how do you reference several duplicates when closing? Is this because someone already flagged the question?

Comment: @mozway *How?* With the *edit* button next to the duplicates. Not sure at what rep level you can use that. — *Why?* Because I'm closing as the first best duplicate I find, and sometimes find better ones afterwards, or multiple dupes may be necessary to answer a question in full.

Comment: ```
name_lists=[]
d = {}
flag = ""
while(flag != "N"):
    d["name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
    d["surname"] = input("Enter a surname: ")
    d["patronmic"] = input("Enter a patronmic: ")
    d["id_number"] = input("Enter a worker's id number: ")
    name_lists.append(d)
    d = {}
    flag = input("Continue inputting data Y/N: ")
print(name_lists)
```

Added a new statement to reinitialise d to an empty dict.

Comment: @deceze I guess I don't have access to this function yet, but good to know that it exists! Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `d` instantiation inside the loop, or you will overwrite the data at each step:

```
name_lists=[]
flag = ""
while(flag != "N"):
    d = {}
    d["name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
    d["surname"] = input("Enter a surname: ")
    d["patronmic"] = input("Enter a patronmic: ")
    d["id_number"] = input("Enter a worker's id number: ")
    name_lists.append(d)
    flag = input("Continue inputting data Y/N: ")
print(name_lists)
```

example output:

```
[{'name': 'a', ...}, {'name': 'b', ...}]
```